# java scanner get data and detected enter each numbers and characters

Tags: java, arrays, loops, java.util.scanner

I'm a beginner to the Java language. Firstly I want use a Scanner to retrieve data

For example, I enter this: `990921205 v`

How can I detect the first 2 numbers for any calculation?
How can I detect each numbers for an algorithm?

I tried this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ID2 {


    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in=new Scanner (System.in);
        int num[]=new int[3];
        int A=0;
        int B=0;
        int C=0;

        System.out.println("enter a number " +A);

    }
}
```

Comment: `how can i detect first 2 number for any calculation how can i detect each numbers for algorithm` What do you mean by that? Can you elaborate and maybe provide example input and output?

Comment: Though I'd usually direct a person who asked this to the [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), I think at this stage of your studies, you'd be better off talking with your tutor and reviewing examples.

Comment: `Eg : I enter this 990921205 v, how can i detect first 2 number...` -- There aren't two numbers there to detect.  Please elaborate on what input you are expecting and what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: `Scanner` cannot help you here since it needs a delimiter to determine how to parse the data, but in your case all the data ins in a single string. Read the input as a `String`, then parse it manually

Comment: Scan in a `String` and use appropriate methods to extract digits.

Answer (score 1):

With `next()` method of `Scanner` you can obtain user standard input.

```
String userInput = in.next();
int first = Integer.parseInt(userInput.charAt(0));
int second = Integer.parseInt(userInput.charAt(1));
//DO STUFF
```

Answer (score 1):

Well to get the inputted values you can use `Scanner.next()`, but if this inputted value is an int you can also use `Scanner.nextInt()` to read it as an integer:

```
int value1= in.nextInt();
```

Then you will have an integer in the `value1` value.

But if you are entering a string you will use the `Scanner.next()`to get this string and then extract the first two elements:

```
String s=in.next();
int firstTwoval=Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer @bigdestroyer gives this error:
 `The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (char)`

You can just do it with `char` and not with integers at all.
 For example,

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String numInput = input.next();

    char nums[] = new char[numInput.length()];

    for (int i = 0;i < numInput.length(); i++){
        nums[i] = numInput.charAt(i);
        System.out.println("For nums["+i+"] : "+nums[i]);
    }
```

Input:

```
0123456789
```

Output:

```
For nums[0] : 0
For nums[1] : 1
For nums[2] : 2
For nums[3] : 3
For nums[4] : 4
For nums[5] : 5
For nums[6] : 6
For nums[7] : 7
For nums[8] : 8
For nums[9] : 9
```

Now since you want the first 2,3,4++ digits, you can apply the answer @chsdk gave.
If you use mine you have to parse them to integer using `Integer.parseInt()` to be sure that it's an actual number.